# cursor.fetchall() or other method fetchone() is not working

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have 2 methods... Method1 one works fine but method 2 `cursor.fetchall()` doesn't show anything, remains empty like `[]`.   If i execute Method2() only it's works fine, problem occurs only when i execute Method1() first and then Method2()

```py
def Method1():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    pocode = ['NWB126280']
    query = "select columnname from dbname.tablename where columnname= %s"
    cursor.execute(query, pocode)
    record = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    print(record)


def Method2():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    file = open('path')
    request_json = file.read()
    payload = {'ApiOwner': ApiDetails.ApiOwner, 'RequestBody': request_json, 'ApiKey': 
    ApiDetails.ApiKey}
    response = requests.post(ApiDetails.url, headers=ApiDetails.headers, data=payload)
    response_json = json.loads(response.text)
    pocode = jsonpath.jsonpath(response_json, "$..outputKey")
    query = "select columnname from dbname.tablename where columnname= %s"
    cursor.execute(query, pocode)
    record = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    print(record)


Method1()
Method2()
```

Comment: Make sure `pocode` in `Method2` coming same as `Method1`

Comment: Do a `print(pocode)` after `pocode` and see how that comes out. If that is wrong, move back a layer until you find the right response. The issue is with how that is generated assuming all else is the same.

Comment: @Poojan pocode in both methods are different. In method2 i am using pocode retruned from post API call.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb did already and pocode is coming fine in post api response. Plase note pocode in  method2 is different from method 1.

Comment: Then query result might be different if `pocode` is different. In your `Method2`. You can print the value of `pocode` in second methdo and debug form there. Its likely that there is no column namematching your `pocode` check db for this. You can run generated query from second method directly in db and see whats the result.

Comment: Do `method1` with the pocode manually input that returns in `method2` and see what happens...

Comment: @Poojan If i remove below lines from Method2                                                              file = open('path')
    request_json = file.read()
    payload = {'ApiOwner': ApiDetails.ApiOwner, 'RequestBody': request_json, 'ApiKey': 
    ApiDetails.ApiKey}
    response = requests.post(ApiDetails.url, headers=ApiDetails.headers, data=payload)
    response_json = json.loads(response.text)
    pocode = jsonpath.jsonpath(response_json, "$..outputKey")                                               And simply keep pocode =  ['newpocode/or the same as in method1'] it works fine.

Comment: Did you try setting `pocode` during debug for testing? Did you try the same query manually on the SQL server? Seems if the query is the same between functions the problem must be in the variable. Design note: consider moving the JSON stuff into it's own function and combining 1 and 2.

Comment: That means whatever `pocode` you are getting from `request` is not present in your db. Run query in your db manually and see if its there or not. In terms of code your first and second method are same. Difference is that in second method you are getting `pocode` dynamically which is cause of problem. Make sure this `pocode` is correct.

Comment: @Poojan i have checked that already, pocode is available in database. If i removed code related to getting value from request and simply provide the value with variable it works fine.

Comment: As i mensioned in previous comment only problem in your code is `pocode` in second method. Since we dont have access to this we cant debug on this, Just debug on `pocode` in second method. Thats all i can help.

Comment: def Method1():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    file = open('path')
    request_json = file.read()
    payload = {'ApiOwner': ApiDetails.ApiOwner, 'RequestBody': request_json, 'ApiKey': 
    ApiDetails.ApiKey}
    response = requests.post(ApiDetails.url, headers=ApiDetails.headers, data=payload)
    response_json = json.loads(response.text)
    pocode = jsonpath.jsonpath(response_json, "$..outputKey")
    query = "select columnname from dbname.tablename where columnname= %s"
    cursor.execute(query, pocode)
    record = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    print(record)

Comment: def Method2():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    file = open('path')
    request_json = file.read()
    payload = {'ApiOwner': ApiDetails.ApiOwner, 'RequestBody': request_json, 'ApiKey': 
    ApiDetails.ApiKey}
    response = requests.post(ApiDetails.url, headers=ApiDetails.headers, data=payload)
    response_json = json.loads(response.text)
    pocode = jsonpath.jsonpath(response_json, "$..outputKey")
    query = "select columnname from dbname.tablename where columnname= %s"
    cursor.execute(query, pocode)
    record = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    print(record)

Comment: Above are Method1() and Method2()....If i call methods like 
Method1()
Method2() 
   
Method2() fails as cursor.fetchall() comes blank.

And if i call Method 2() first like below
Method2()  
Method1()

then Method1() fails as cursor.fetchall() comes blank. I am totally confused why this is happening

Answer (score 2):

After trying it multiple times. I understand that you always have to commit  (`db.commit()`) your transaction into databases before executing new `cursor.fetchall()`.

Always commit transaction before executing a new query.

After doing this change my code worked as expected.

```
def Method1():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    pocode = ['NWB126280']
    query = "select columnname from dbname.tablename where columnname= %s"
    cursor.execute(query, pocode)
    db.commit()
    record = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    print(record)


def Method2():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    file = open('path')
    request_json = file.read()
    payload = {'ApiOwner': ApiDetails.ApiOwner, 'RequestBody': request_json, 'ApiKey': 
    ApiDetails.ApiKey}
    response = requests.post(ApiDetails.url, headers=ApiDetails.headers, data=payload)
    response_json = json.loads(response.text)
    pocode = jsonpath.jsonpath(response_json, "$..outputKey")
    query = "select columnname from dbname.tablename where columnname= %s"
    cursor.execute(query, pocode)
    record = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    print(record)
```

Comment: This addressed my problem as well.  Everywhere I look on the net, articles demonstrate the commit() function in conjuction with modifying something (UPDATE or INSERT).  In my case, the results of a SELECT query using cursor.execute() were coming back as zero-length without a commit() - but only sometimes.

It should be noted that this behaviour wasn't exhibited when running my script in an interactive-mode, but was required when running a script as an entrypoint in that same docker container.